# Is there a way to set the same font for the whole document in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I am writing a document in LaTeX (it is a report but the class used is book) that contains many images, tables and not a lot of text. Since the final file must be 500 kb (orders from Above ...) and since by compressing the file (I tried with GhostScript) I can't go below 800kb with 72 dpi images, I thought if the problem were the different fonts present in the document.
So is there a way to make the font of the document (captions, index, formulas ... everything!) unique?
Thanks

Comment: What output format are you using? PDF? There are ways to optimize / compress that, after the compilation, as it were. I have personally used https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt with great success.

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks! I've just tried, but the file is still too heavy! 1.1 MB. The original PDF is 1.6 MB

Comment: LaTeX uses the same font for the whole document unless you tell it to do otherwise. What type of images does your document contain? If they are diagrams or plots, then they can probably be stored more efficiently in a vector format such as pdf. A bitmap format (jpg, png, etc.) will produce poor results whatever dpi you use. On the other hand, if the images are photographs (or similar) then vector graphics can't help.

Comment: @Ian Thompson all images are in .pdf format, saved directly from matlab. I really think I have reached a "physical" limit of the document

Comment: You can try switching the images off temporarely using `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` in your preamble instead of just `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Then you can see the size of the document without the images, that would be the upper bound of the reduction that you can achieve by doing non-image related size reduction tricks. I suspect that will show that the images are (literally) the biggest problem, and reducing other content will not be sufficient.

Comment: I don't suppose you could put all the images on a web page and just link to them? ;-)

Comment: if the images are from matlab can't you save them in a scalable format rather than 72dbi bitmaps?

Comment: @Marijn, I've just tried but LaTeX says "Option clash for package graphicx". It's on Overleaf.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Unfortunately no!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, If I enter the .svg format directly, overleaf gives an error

Comment: the svg package allows inclusion of svg but only via converting to pdf in the background, you'd be better getting matlab to generate pdf I would expect Oh I see you say they are pdf in a comment above in which case I do not understand your 72dpi comment?

Comment: If you get an option clash that is unrelated to overleaf or the features available it just means that you have loaded the graphics package twice, with different options, so a user error in the document. the help text of that error message will suggest a possible fix.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, When I import images from matlab I select 300dpi from the console. Maybe am I wrong? Do I have to change everything to 72dpi? But then when I go to print the result is bad ..

Comment: dpi only has meaning for a bitmap if it is a scalable format that doesn't really have dots that can be counted per inch